# In SQLAlchemy, how do I create a many-to-many-to-many model?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I got 3 tables:

- Chapter
- Namespace
- Tag

A Tag can be in multiple Namespace's, and a Namespace can contain multiple Tag's.

A Chapter can have multiple combinations of Namespace and Tag.

I've done this before in pure SQL, but I'm somehow having trouble doing it in SQLAlchemy.

[This model illustrates what I'm seeking, and is how I implemented it in pure SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGzcK.png)

This is how I want to deal with them in real code:

```
chapter.tags # returns a list of unique combinations of Namespace and Tag

namespace.tags # returns a list of all tags this namespace is combined with

tag.namespaces # returns a list of all namespaces that contain this tag
```

Thanks!